# Bug in image blitting algorihtm - 'italic' output

Tags: c++, image-processing

I've got a function which blits some region of source image to destination image. And there is a problem: I've got a bug in it but I can't find it. Probably it's very trivial, but I spent many hours on it :). My algorithm 'tilts' objects on image. In debugging i saw that it copies a little more pixels than it should (e.g 36836 instead 36481)

```
struct Point
{
    unsigned x, y;

    Point(unsigned x, unsigned y) : x(x), y(y) { }
    Point() : x(0), y(0) { }
};

struct Rect
{
    Point lt, rd; // left-top and right-down vertexs
};

struct Img
{
    vector<unsigned char> px; // pixel data in linear form (RBGARBGARBGA...)
    unsigned w, h; // width and heigth of image
};

inline bool isInRect(const Point& p, const Rect& r)
{
    return (p.x >= r.lt.x && p.y >= r.lt.y && p.x <= r.rd.x && p.y <= r.rd.y);
}

unsigned blit(const Img& src, Img& dest, const Rect& reg) // <--- THIS FUNCTION
{
    dest.w = reg.rd.x - reg.lt.x;
    dest.h = reg.rd.y - reg.lt.y;

    dest.px.clear();

    unsigned n = 0;

    for(int i = (reg.lt.y * src.w + reg.lt.x) * 4; i < src.px.size(); i += 4)
    {
        unsigned y = (i / 4) / src.w;
        unsigned x = (i / 4) % src.w;

        if(isInRect(Point(x, y), reg))
        {
            dest.px.push_back(src.px[i]);
            dest.px.push_back(src.px[i + 1]);
            dest.px.push_back(src.px[i + 2]);
            dest.px.push_back(src.px[i + 3]);
            n += 4;
        }

        if(y > reg.rd.y)
            break;
    }
    return n / 4;
}
```

Example:

Image fragment to blit: http://www.mediafire.com/view/1rb8dyc4z8xq5rl/arial-toblit.PNG

Algorithm output: http://www.mediafire.com/view/qe9j38gq5tp299v/arial-A.png

Comment: I would start with verifying the calculations for small rectangles by hand, using pencil and paper, away from the computer.

Comment: On paper it looks that function adds 'extra' pixel for each row and each next row shifts one pixel relative to row before. Maybe bug is somewhere in isInRect() (does this function include 1 extra pixel to rectangle?)

Comment: If you use the `Rect` `{{0,0}, {1,1}}` in `isInRect`, the four points `{0,0}`, `{0,1}`, `{1,0}`, `{1,1}` will be considered to be inside it, i.e. a four-pixel square. I don't know what your intent is, but that `Rect` would set the width and height of `dest` to 1 in `blit`. One of those must be wrong, and you need to decide which one. (Which is the "one-pixel" `Rect` - `{{0,0}, {1,1}}` or `{{0,0}, {0,0}}`?)

Comment: Indeed, i should write `p.x < r.rd.x && p.y < r.rd.y` instead `p.x <= r.rd.x && p.y <= r.rd.y`. Thanks!